# Load XML document from Stored Procedure where document is on Windows server

Tags: xml, oracle11g, sql-loader

We currently have an in house built patching mechanism that runs on a Windows application server.  The staging files for the patch are located on a shared SAN accessed via a UNC path.  We currently run utilities on the application server with embedded PL/SQL or directly execute Stored Procedures to manage our Oracle 11g DB objects.

I have a new requirement to load an XML file that exists under the UNC path mentioned above and load it into a table in Oracle.  Given the following limitations on where the input file can reside;

[image: Options]

it appears we have the following options;

1. Write a utility and shell out to the OS to execute either SQL*Plus or SQL*Loader to load the XML.  Note our patching mechanism is not able to call script files.
2. Mount an external Samba share to the UNC path and use External Tables, (not sure this will work), and call from SP
3. Write a utility to copy the XML to the Oracle server and use External Tables or UTL_FILE to load.

Any other options?  Am I missing something obvious?

Kurt

Answer (score 0):

There's another option which is SQLcl : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html

It's the scripting engine out of sqldev factored down into a command line. Since it's java based, it can also do some client side coding.  There's more details on the scripting on github [here](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-tools/blob/master/sqlcl/SCRIPTING.md). Here's a sample that loads all files in a directory into a table.

```
drop table k
/
CREATE TABLE K
(   PATH VARCHAR2(2000),
    BLOB_CONTENT BLOB,
    WHEN TIMESTAMP (6)
)
/
script

/* create a temp blob to be used in the insert */
getBlobFromFile=function (fileName){
   try {
     var b = conn.createBlob();
     var out = b.setBinaryStream(1);
     var path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(fileName);
     java.nio.file.Files.copy(path, out);
     out.flush();
     return b;
  } catch(e){
    ctx.write(e);
  }
};


var File = Java.type("java.io.File")
var FilenameFilter = Java.type("java.io.FilenameFilter")
/* Files */
var dir = "."
var cwd = new File(dir);
var allFiles = cwd.listFiles();


for(var file in allFiles){
     /* only load files not dirs */
     if (allFiles[file].isFile() ){
          /* define binds */
          var binds = {}
          /* add path/filename as a bind */
          binds.path=allFiles[file].toString().substring(2);

          ctx.write("Loading:"+  allFiles[file]  + "\n")

          blob = getBlobFromFile(allFiles[file]);

              ctx.write("\t>"+ blob.length()+":" + allFiles[file]  + "\n")
              binds.b = blob;
              /* exec the insert and pass binds */
              var ret = util.execute("insert into k(path,blob_content,when) values(:path , :b,systimestamp)",binds);
              var ex = util.getLastException();
              if ( ex ){
                ctx.write(ex+ "\n")

               }
      }
}
/
select path,dbms_lob.getlength(blob_content) from k order by when desc
/
```

Then in this table

```
**PATH**                       **DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(BLOB_CONTENT)** 
sync.js                                                3924 
rspool.sql                                              105 
chew_roar.wav                                        256810 
customjson.sql                                           92
```